# Having trouble removing undefined values from javascript objects (Web Dev Simplified)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, game-engine

Sorry i know this has been asked before but the solutions i have tried dont seem to be working :(

I need the undefined values to not appear when i look at the simple inventory i've built in HTML.

```
function pullValue() {
    var node = document.createElement("li");
    var textNode = (document.createTextNode(state.thing1 + " " +  state.thing2 + " " + state.thing3));
    node.appendChild(textNode);
    document.getElementById("inventory").appendChild(node);
```

/////I have tried the below solutions with no luck :( ////////

```
    Object.keys(state).forEach(key => state[key] === undefined && delete state[key]);

   state.filter(Boolean);

   var ret = (state.thing1 + state.thing2 + state.thing3).replace(/undefined/g,'');

    var filtered = state.filter(Boolean);

}
```

(thing1, 2 and 3 are part of the state object)

```
let state = {}
```

I've been trying to build an inventory system from the code established in this Web Dev Simplified video: https://youtu.be/R1S_NhKkvGA

Answer (score 0):

I used short-circuiting to relace undefined with "". if you need spaces u can try ternary operator to use state.thing1 + " " or "" like

`state.thing ? state.thing + " " : ""` and the next state

```
function pullValue() {
    var node = document.createElement("li");
    var textNode = (document.createTextNode(state.thing1 || "" + state.thing2 || "" + state.thing3 || ""));
    node.appendChild(textNode);
    document.getElementById("inventory").appendChild(node);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution by Kishore is perfect. But, if you want to return every defined element in the state object, you can use the Objects.values() function instead. Make a new textNodeItems variable and return all available values.

```
var textNodeItems = Object.values(state);
```

And then proceed to add the textNodeItems variable to the textNode varaible.

```
var textNode = (document.createTextNode(textNodeItems));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both so much for your help!!! Spent my whole day off work trying to suss this one out ;( - im still relatively new to javascript.

So in the end i went with:

```
function pullValue() {
    var node = document.createElement("li");
    var textNodeItems = Object.values(state);
    var textNode = (document.createTextNode(textNodeItems));
    node.appendChild(textNode);
    document.getElementById("inventory").appendChild(node);
}
```

I will have to post my code up on Github when im done with this project and link it in the comments in the youtube video above as others were struggling in the comments.